# Do the two equations agree?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Look at the equation 
$$\tag{1}\nabla g(a)=\lambda \nabla h(a),$$ 
must be satisfied at any random point $a$ when $g$'s is on the level set $\{x: h(x)=b\}$ and has an extreme. But in the case when $g$ has a local extreme at $a$, then 
$$\tag{2}\nabla g(a)= 0.$$

Do the two equations agree with each other?

Comment: This looks like something involving lagrange multipliers but your choice of terminology escapes me, so i'll leave it to someone else ot answer. In the event that you can simplify the language, maybe I could try to help out with the logic. :)

Comment: Bump ? No idea? @frogeyedpeas

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that could happen. In that case $\lambda = 0$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/525175)

Comment: @Vlad : My answer might be short, but I think I am answering the question...

Comment: Aren't we supposed to provide comprehensive answer, not just consider one particular case? If this is the only case when equation agree, then it would be nice to show or at least mention it in your answer. OP asks _"Do the two equations agree with each other?"_. Your reply  _"that could happen"_ seems to be indicating possibility rather than asserting something. I feel this might not be sufficient to count as an answer.

Comment: @Vlad: I said that could happen, since, really, when doing Lagrange multiplier, the case $\nabla g =0$ might or might not happen. I assume you know this. That doesn't mean anything, just that $\lambda = 0$.

Comment: $\text{@JohnMa}$, I agree with your previous comment, in particular with the last sentence _"That doesn't mean anything, just that $\,\lambda=0\,$"_. In fact, I believe it reinforces my concern about your post not attempting to give an answer to the original straightforward question *"Do the two equations agree with each other?"*. In the post you are only saying _"maybe"_ without attempting to cover general case or even vaguely describing conditions necessary for the answer to be either "yes" or "no".

Comment: $\text{@JohnMa}$, I am trying my best to explain the reason I pick up on the post. English is my second language, so I apologize if I was not able to make myself clear. In that case, please feel free to let me know you are having troubles following my logic regarding your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is that $g$ constrained to the surface $h(x)=b$ can only have an extreme at a point $a$ on that surface if all the directional derivatives of $g$ in the tangent plane to the surface at at the point $a$ are equal to $0$.

$\nabla h(a)$is the normal vector to the tangent plane 

if  $\nabla g(a)$ is also normal to the tangent plane at $a$ 
then all direction derivatives vanish and we have an extreme.

This is the basis for $\nabla g(a)=\lambda \nabla h(a)$

If it should happen that there exists a point $p$ on the surface for which $\nabla g(p)=\vec 0$ then certainly all the directional derivatives of $g$ will vanish at $p$ so the point $p$ is both a constrained and an unconstrained extreme.